# Automated search in google

Tags: html, vba, hyperlink, automation

I have over 20,000 searches I need to do in google. I want to use VBA to do an automate search in google or internet explorer and return link to excel. I have tried multiple VBA formulas and none of them seem to work. Is there a formula that will do an automate search and return link to the first site on google search to excel? Below is the formula I am currently using, but it isn't working. I am searching addresses in column A and need link to be return to column B.

```
Sub XMLHTTP_Count()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

    If html.getElementById("resultStats") Is Nothing Then
        str_text = "0 Results"
    Else
        str_text = html.getElementById("resultStats").innerText
    End If
        Cells(i, 2) = str_text
        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: What isn't working specifically? This isn't enough information to know how to help.

Comment: The formula works but only pulls the link for one of the 20,000 rows. It doesn't return links to all the rows

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need the randomizer and it looks like the 'resultStats' changed to 'result-stats'.  Try the code below and see if it does what you want.

```
Sub GetSearchStats()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date
    Dim var As String
    Dim var1 As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)
        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rso")
        Set var1 = html.getElementById("result-stats")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText

        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The formula works but I want it to return to the google search page. For example, in column A the states "Novotel Visakhapatnam Varun Beach Andhra Pradesh IND 530003" I want it to do a google search and return the link to results.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered your initial question.  This sounds like a new question , and it probably warrants a new post, but I'll go ahead and offer a second answer here, to address this question.

```
Sub WebPage()

    Dim internet As Object
    Dim internetdata As Object
    Dim div_result As Object
    Dim header_links As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim URL As String

    Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    internet.Visible = True

    URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+program+in+vba"
    internet.Navigate URL

    Do Until internet.ReadyState >= 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

    Set internetdata = internet.Document
    Set div_result = internetdata.getelementbyid("res")


    Set header_links = div_result.getelementsbytagname("h3")

    For Each h In header_links
        Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)
        Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = link.href
    Next

    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

You can easily convert each text field to a hyperlink if you want to make thse all clickable links.  Feel free to modify the code to suit your needs.